# Tkinter Text widget maximum recursion depth using idlelib Delegator/Percolator

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

After testing I have concluded that the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    text.mainloop()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1009, \
                                                                      in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

occurs only after there is a character before the INSERT position and the user types a Backspace. Here is my code:

```
# Import
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext

import idlelib.Delegator
import idlelib.WidgetRedirector
import idlelib.Percolator
import idlelib.ColorDelegator

import time
import re

# Class
class Highlighter(idlelib.Delegator.Delegator):
    def __init__(self):
        idlelib.Delegator.Delegator.__init__(self)
        self._syntaxes = {}
        self._compiled = ""

    def setdelegate(self, delegate):
        idlelib.Delegator.Delegator.setdelegate(self, delegate)
        if delegate is not None:
            self.setup()

    def insert(self, index, chars, *args):
        index = self.index(index)
        self.delegate.insert(index, chars, *args)
        self.update(index, index + "+%dc" % len(chars))

    def delete(self, index1, index2=None):
        index = self.index(index1)
        self.delete(index1, index2)
        self.update(index)

    def update(self, index1, index2=None):
        self.tag_add("TODO", index1, index2)
        self.after(1, self.syntax_highlight)

    def setup(self):
        background = self.cget("background")
        self.tag_configure("TODO", foreground=background, background=None)

    def syntax_configure(self, tag, syntax):
        """Configure syntax TAG with pattern SYNTAX."""
        self._syntaxes[tag] = syntax

    syntax_config = syntax_configure

    def syntax_cget(self, tag):
        """Return the pattern of TAG."""
        return self._syntaxes[tag]

    def syntax_delete(self, tag):
        """Delete syntax TAG from the highlighter."""
        self._syntaxes.pop(tag)

    def syntax_clear(self):
        """Clear all syntaxes."""
        self._syntaxes.clear()

    def syntax_compile(self):
        """Compile all syntaxes."""
        return "|".join("(?P<%s>%s)" % (tag, pattern)
                        for tag, pattern in self._syntaxes.items())

    def syntax_highlight(self, start="1.0", end="end"):
        start = self.index(start)
        end = self.index(end)
        pattern = self.syntax_compile()
        if pattern:
            for match in re.finditer(pattern, self.get(start, end)):
                tag, sequence = list(match.groupdict().items())[0]
                start, stop = match.span()
                self.tag_remove("TODO", "1.0", "1.0+%dc" % match.span()[1])
                self.tag_add(tag, "1.0+%dc" % start, "1.0+%dc" % stop)
        self.tag_delete("TODO")

text = tkinter.Text()
text.pack()
p = idlelib.Percolator.Percolator(text)
h = Highlighter()
p.insertfilter(h)
text.mainloop()
```

If anyone could explain what the cause/source of the recursion is, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that instead of `self.delete(index1, index2)` in `delete` it should have been `self.delegate.delete(index1, index2)`.